# solucionar política Cors en javascript

Tags: javascript, html, pixijs

hola gente estube haciendo un toturial que me parecia intereceante usando la libreria pixi:
dejo el Tuto: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FgN2EENWPFc&t=81s
dejo la pagina de Pixi para las librerías: https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/releases
estaba siguiendo los pasos todo bien y me tope con 2 problema el primero es que la librería sin puntos de pagina no me funciona pero eso supuesta mente esta solucionado.

el problema esta en que me tira este error al usar esta o cualquier imagen

"from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https." el tema es que nose como se soluciona y que es esto directamente así que quería preguntar si alguien sabe.

dejo el código para que vean si es que me equivoco en algo de tipeado por si las dudas también

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <title>3D Pikachu</title>
</head>
<body>
 <script src="pixi.js"></script>
 <script>
  
  let app= new PIXI.Application({width: window.innerWidth,height: window.innerHeight});
  document.body.appendChild(app.view);

  let img = new PIXI.Sprite.from("pikachu.jpg")
  img.width =window.innerWidth;
  img.height =window.innerHeight;

  app.stage.addChild(img);
  </script>

 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Estas trabajando sin un webserver, es decir que en el navegador abres un archivo html que esta en tu pc directamente (url file://...) al igual que la imagen que querés abrir?

Comment: sis exacto pero igual que significa que la tengo que buscar desde internet y pasar la urlpara que funque?

Comment: Lo mas simple y seguro es que uses un webserver para desarrollar y pongas los archivos ahí. Lo que podes probar pero no creo que funcione es cambiar "pikachu.jpg" por "file://<ruta completa>/pikachu.jpg" y que la imagen esté en la misma carpeta que el html y el javascript.

Comment: Lo mismo con la ruta de pixi.js

Comment: okey ahora si no puedo usar una ruta web xq yo soy el que hacer la imagen que hago?

Comment: igual ojo ya me fije y lo que pasa es que en MI compu da problemas en otra lo probe y funca asi que ni idea que onda

Comment: Instalate un webserver en tu compu y poné los archivos ahi dentro. Puede ser un xamp o alguno más liviano.